# How to calculate a heading on the earths surface?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-geometry

Given an initial position and a subsequent position, each given by latitude and longitude in the WGS-84 system.  How do you determine the heading in degrees clockwise from true north of movement?

Comment: Adding a little more detail to your question would be nice. Not knowing a lot about the field, I had no idea what WGS-84 was, so I would have to look it up:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84

Comment: Is it correct to say that your question is: Given an initial position and a subsequent position, each given by latitude and longitude in the WGS-84 system, determine the heading in degrees clockwise from true north of movement?

Comment: @Isaac Exactly. I changed the phrasing of the question yours is clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, some background.  A "line" (the object containing the path of least distance between two points) on a sphere is a great circle; a great circle is the intersection of a sphere with a plane passing through the center of the sphere.  A spherical triangle is the triangle formed by the spherical line segments connecting three non-collinear points on a sphere.  Below is the Spherical Law of Cosines as it appears in UCSMP *Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry*, 3rd ed., copied here because the diagram is good and helps with clarity.

[image: Spherical Law of Cosines (from UCSMP Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry, 3rd ed.)]

If ABC is a spherical triangle with arcs a, b, and c (meaning the measures of the arcs, not the lengths), then cos c = cos a * cos b + sin a * sin b * cos C.

Now, to the specific problem at hand.  Let's use the diagram below, also from UCSMP *Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry*, 3rd ed., for reference.

[image: globe (from UCSMP Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry, 3rd ed.)]

Let B be the initial point and A be the final point of the movement (and for simplicity, I'll assume they are both in the northern hemisphere, and leave extending the solution to any points as an exercise); N and S are the north and south poles, respectively; C and D are the points on the equator that are on the same line of longitude as A and B, respectively.  Consider spherical triangle ABN.  a = (90° - latitude of point A); b = (90° - latitude of point B). N = positive difference in longitude between points A and B.  Use the Spherical Law of Cosines (cos n = ... form) to determine n, then use the Spherical Law of Cosines (cos b = ... form) to determine B.  If the points are arranged as pictured, the heading of travel from B to A is 360° - B; for other arrangements of the points, the exact method of determining the heading based on the measure of angle B may vary.

*(graphics from Lesson 5-10 of UCSMP Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry, 3rd ed., © 2010 Wright Group/McGraw Hill)*

Comment: Pretty much clears up every question about the topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with spherical geometry, but when you are talking about WGS-84 you are not on a sphere anymore but on a ellipsoid and things become a little more complex.

To my mind, the best answer to the original question is:

Karney, C.F.F. J Geod (2013) 87: 43. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z

Comment: +1 It's not uncommon, at introductory level, to compute distance and heading on Earth using only spherical trigonometry and assuming the Earth is a sphere. It give a not too bad approximation. However, you are right, any accurate computation must use a [reference ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid) (and computing geodesics on an ellipsoid is much more difficult).