# Napier's Rules applied to spherical distance calculations

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-geometry

I was in the middle of writing the same old geographic distance calculation using the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) when it occurred to me: shouldn't there be simpler way to do this? Haversine is of course derived from the Law of Cosines. But in thinking about this problem, I ran across [Napier's Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) for right-angled spherical triangles. It seems like Napier's Rules should apply, after all Latitude small circles and Longitude great circles always intersect at right angles, so you should be able to draw a right-angled spherical triangle where the hypotenuse connects any two points (unless the case devolves into a line or single point).

So if I'm applying Napier's Rules correctly, if our delta latitude and delta longitude in radians are $a$ and $b$ respectively, the angle $c$ should trace the arc between the two points. So Napier says:

$\sin(\pi-c) = \cos(a) \cos(b)$

Which should then simplify to:

$c = \arcsin(\cos(a) \cos(b))$

But when I try to verify this with a couple test points, the result doesn't match the Haversine formula. Is there a mistake in my (admittedly rusty) algebra or is my mistake in assuming I can apply Napier's Rules to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latitude "lines" are not spherical-geometry lines, as they are not great circles, so the "triangles" you are getting are not spherical triangles.

Comment: I think I understand: you're saying Napier's doesn't apply unless all of the arcs involved are sections of great circles?

Comment: Yes, the Napier formulae are meant only for spherical triangles, triangles whose sides are arcs of great circles. Remember that only the equator and the prime meridian are the great circles on the globe.

Comment: In my readings I never found that definition. I thought that a "spherical triangle" was any triangle drawn on a sphere. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: Correction to that last comment of mine: *all* the meridians/longitudes are great circles, but among the latitudes, only the equator is a great circle.

Comment: @JavadocMD: The shortest distance along the surface of a sphere between two points is along the great circle through those two points, so line segments in spherical geometry have to be arcs of great circles.  The three sides of a triangle have to be line segments, so they must be arcs of great circles.  And, as J.M. said, all lines of longitude are great circles, but the equator is the only line of latitude that is a great circle.

Comment: I've typically done problems like I think you're describing using the Spherical Law of Cosines, as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720/how-to-calculate-a-heading-on-the-earths-surface/770#770), but I suspect that works out to be equivalent to the haversine formula.

Comment: @JavadocMD: You'll sometimes see "The shortest distance along the surface of a sphere between two points is along the great circle through those two points" stated instead as "segments of great circles are *geodesics* on a sphere."

Answer (score 1):

Napier's rule can be applied to solve problems in spherical geometry and I suggest you may apply your angles in such an equation. Sine of the middle part = product of cosines of opposite parts.So $\sin(90-c)=\cos a x \cos b$, considering a as the angle to be found.
$\cos a = \cos c$ divided by $\cos b$. where the angle between 100 and 110 is $b$ , and the  distance in terms of an angle between the centre of the circle 001 and 110 is $c$. Keep in mind the principles of stereographic projection  while converting angles to distance and vice-versa.